# iOS: ImageIO resizing on a rectangular image

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, javax.imageio

I'm trying to create thumbnails of images for my app. I'm using *CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex* to do it. One problem I'm seeing is that for the options, *kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize* is the max pixel size for both width and height.

The problem I'm having is: I have an image that is 500w x 1000h and I want to scale it down to say 250w x 500h. When I use *CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex* I want to specify the width to be 250 but instead it seems to be making my height 250 instead.

How can I use this to scale down a rectangular image by width?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Provide value (kCFBooleanTrue) to the key `kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform` in the Options provided to `CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex` and the thumbnail should be rotated and scaled according to the orientation and pixel aspect ratio of the full image.

This is the documentation of this Key

```
/* Specifies whether the thumbnail should be rotated and scaled according
 * to the orientation and pixel aspect ratio of the full image. The value
 * of this key must be a CFBooleanRef; the default value of this key is 
 * kCFBooleanFalse. */

IMAGEIO_EXTERN const CFStringRef kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform  IMAGEIO_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_4, __IPHONE_4_0);
```

You can modify this implementation to provide the max value you want instead of the size

Category added to UIImage to resize it using ImageIO

UIImage+Resizing.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImage (Resizing)

-(UIImage*)resizedImageWithData:(NSData*)imageData withSize:(CGSize)size;

@end
```

UIImage+Resizing.m

```
#import "UIImage+Resizing.h"
#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>

@implementation UIImage (Resizing)

-(UIImage*)resizedImageWithData:(NSData*)imageSource withSize:(CGSize)size{
    //  Resizing Using ImageIO
    CGImageSourceRef src = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)imageSource, nil);

    // load the image at the desired size
    NSDictionary* options = @{
                        (id)kCGImageSourceShouldAllowFloat: (id)kCFBooleanTrue,
                        (id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform: (id)kCFBooleanTrue,
                        (id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways: (id)kCFBooleanTrue,
                        (id)kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: @((int)(size.width > size.height ? size.width : size.height))
                        };

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(src, 0, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)options);
    if (NULL != src)
        CFRelease(src);

    UIImage* scaledImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    if (NULL != imageRef)
        CFRelease(imageRef);

    return scaledImage;
}

@end
```

Answer (score -3):

There are many ways to resize image, You can find tons if you google it..

```
- (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image newSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    CGRect newRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height));
    CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, newSize.height);

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);  
    // Draw into the context; this scales the image
    CGContextDrawImage(context, newRect, imageRef);

    // Get the resized image from the context and a UIImage
    CGImageRef newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];

    CGImageRelease(newImageRef);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    

    return newImage;
}
```

Just try these links for more info http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

And [Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=aspect%20scale%20image%20iphone%20sdk&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb) can be your best friend.

Comment: Thanks but of course I have googled it and yes there are tons of ways. My question is specific to being able to do it with CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex, not just any way.